# Updating data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I just met `chart.js` and I'm trying to handle it but it's getting hard for me.

My intention is to initially have some data, `var data = [2478,5267,734,784,433];` but if a button is clicked, these are modified and the table is updated, var `data = [2,5,7,7,4];`

With the code I show below I can do it, but I am really creating a new one and therefore the two overlap me.

```
function pieChart(datos){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");

    var tipo = 'pie';
    var etiquetas = ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"];
    //var datos = [2478,5267,734,784,433];
    var colores = ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"];
    var titulo = 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050';

    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: tipo,
        data: {
            labels: etiquetas,
            datasets: [{
              backgroundColor: colores,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#FFF',
              data: datos
            }]
          },
          options: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: titulo
            }
          }
    });
}

// MAIN
$(document).ready(function(){

    var datos = [2478,5267,734,784,433];
    pieChart(datos);

    // Botón pulsado
    $('.btn_graf').click(function(){
        var id_btn = $(this).attr("id");

        if (id_btn == 'bat_graf_btn'){
            alert('pulsado');
            var datos = [2,5,7,7,4];
            pieChart(datos);
        }
    });
});
```

Reading the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) I see that it can be done by calling a function and adding values ​​to the array and I suppose that the old ones have been previously removed. But I don't know how to do it because I probably have something wrongly done / understood.

```
function pieChart(datos){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");

    var tipo = 'pie';
    var etiquetas = ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"];
    //var datos = [2478,5267,734,784,433];
    var colores = ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"];
    var titulo = 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050';

    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: tipo,
        data: {
            labels: etiquetas,
            datasets: [{
              label: "Population (millions)",
              backgroundColor: colores,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#FFF',
              data: datos,
            }]
          },
          options: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: titulo
            }
          }
    });
}
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}

// MAIN
$(document).ready(function(){

    var datos = [2478,5267,734,784,433];
    pieChart(datos);

    // Botón pulsado
    $('.btn_graf').click(function(){
        var id_btn = $(this).attr("id");

        if (id_btn == 'bat_graf_btn'){
            alert('pulsado');
            var datos = [2,5,7,7,4];
            removeData(myPieChart);
            addData(myPieChart, "Population (millions)", datos);
        }
    });
});
```

If someone can guide me it would be great. I think it is a very useful tool when it comes to graphing information and I would like to learn how to handle it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This: `var datos = [2,5,7,7,4]` declares a second variable also called `datos` which shadows the one declared in the outer scope.  Remove the `var ` so it uses the same variable

Comment: mmm no, it happens the same. Is creating a new one and superposing it. :(

Comment: The graphical display you are attempting to create is making it more difficult to get the data manipulation correct.  Get rid of that stuff until your data is correct.  Just output the values to the console.  The `var` keyword declares a new variable.  That's what it does.  You have two arrays, both called `datos`, each in a different scope that hold different data.  You need to figure out how that works before you create a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access the chart variable, make the scope more accessible.

Initialize it as `null` at the top and assign it in the function. You can then access it later.

```js
const colores = ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"];
const etiquetas = ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"];

var myPieChart = null; // "global" access...

function pieChart(datos) {
  let ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
  let tipo = 'pie';
  let titulo = 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050';

  myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: tipo,
    data: {
      labels: etiquetas,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: colores,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#FFF',
        data: datos,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: titulo
      }
    }
  });
}

function addData(chart, title, data) {
  chart.options.title.text = title;
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
    dataset.data = data;
  });
  chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.pop();
  });
  chart.update();
}

// MAIN
$(document).ready(function() {
  pieChart([2478, 5267, 734, 784, 433]);

  // Botón pulsado
  $('.btn_graf').click(function() {
    let id_btn = $(this).attr("id");

    if (id_btn == 'bat_graf_btn') {
      removeData(myPieChart);
      addData(myPieChart, "Population (millions)", [2, 5, 7, 7, 4]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
<button class="btn_graf" id="bat_graf_btn">Change Data</button>
```

Comment: @NEA I had to modify your `addData()` function. See the updated code above.